# What is wslite?

Tags: php, mysql

In a PHP+Mysql web game I have a form that saves the name of the player.

A week ago I've noticed that some stranges names have appeared in the beta domain (I have a main domain where the people plays and a "beta domain" that I use for making tests)

The names:

- Ans:wslite
- javascript:alert(wslite)
- ../../../../../wslite/../../../../../boot.ini.htm
- `<wslite>`
- Ans:wslite=true

I've googled wslite and seems that is like a ...plugin for groovy? It have any sense? What could be these codes and why are inserted in the application?

Comment: at least one of them is a hack attempt, you want to be real careful with user input.

Comment: You're not the only one: http://scarletlegacy.gamescampus.com/community/gallerydetail/1/14065

Comment: @user: could you give me address of your browser game? I'm interested

Comment: @genesis φ The game is www.frikitrivial.com, and the beta domain is beta.frikitrivial.com (it's in spanish)

Comment: about the downvote, is anything wrong with the question? Maybe with a explanation I can edit and improve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably some exploit in that software,whatever is it. And some "hackers" are trying to use it. I'd suggest you to block them and try to find all exploits in your server/software

Comment: mmm... about the inputs i've tested against sql injection and XSS. About the server, I've take a look but since is a shared hosting I don't know if there is much to do with it

Comment: @user674887: you should move VPS to be more secure

Comment: thanks for the advice. For now I'll be in a shared hosting for the price, but I'll think about it.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about this *too* much. at the very worst it means your inputs are secure. I downloaded a 'web exploit scanner' called 'websecurify' to test a local version of a todo list I'm working on. It goes through, clicks all the links, submits potential exploits into all the textboxes and what not.

So all that stuff is just where the exploit scanner has submitted stuff to your site. My entire todo list contained stuff like:

```
../../../../../e8sBu/../../../../../boot.ini�.htm
" onerror="f(e8sBu)
```

Answer (score 1):

Either it's some bad guys trying to hack into your community, or it's somebody testing your community's security level. It's done by using some of free Website Penetration tests found all around the web. I did some testing on my website and found exactly the same stuff in database. Double check your login security :)